# Size and performance different on UPDATE with/out intermediate CTE

Tags: postgresql, update, performance, postgresql-performance

I've got two tables with an indexes id column in common. I'm trying to add a new column in the `target` table using the value of a column in the `source` table. The two tables are rather large with couple dozen columns or more.

The thing I don't understand is why the two update queries I've tried perform so wildly different.

This update takes more than an hour before failing due to lack of space (gobbled up +120gb of storage)

```sql
UPDATE target
SET created_at = src.created_at
FROM base_table src
WHERE src.id = target.id
```

While the following took 5 minutes and did not make a dent in space:

```sql
WITH subtable AS (
  SELECT
      id,
      created_at
  FROM base_table
)
UPDATE target
SET created_at = subtable.created_at
FROM subtable
WHERE target.id = subtable.id
```

Is creating an intermediate table with only two columns mean that the entire operation is executed in memory and that's why the two perform so differently? If that's the case I would've expected the optimizer to address this no?

What's happening?

Comment: Please show the EXPLAIN output of both.

Comment: The answer to performance questions always starts with looking at the execution plan. You can also use `explain (analyze)` to get more details. **Attention**: using `explain (analyze)` **will** run that statement - including UPDATE, DELETE or INSERT statements. So you probably want to turn off autocommit and do a rollback after that.

Comment: What is your Postgres version?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Sorry that's correct I tried to anonymize the table names and clearly failed.

Comment: as I know, Postgresql materialized CTE, and in many cases it work slower then inline queries, some more explanation - https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/blog/postgresql-ctes-are-optimization-fences/ or https://medium.com/@hakibenita/be-careful-with-cte-in-postgresql-fca5e24d2119 . CTE as well prevents parallelization, but still good in many cases :-)

Comment: @a_vlad: in this case the CTE made the query _faster_

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I'm struggling to get the query to complete that's why I've not posted anything.